# intent filter for settings activity

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am trying to receive a broadcast whenever the activity manager launches system settings.

What is the intent filter for system settings activity?

Answer (score 0):

No intent is broadcasted when System Settings are launched. But you can create a service and check the top activity in activity stack like that:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> processes = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
ComponentName componentInfo = processes.get(0).topActivity;
String className = componentInfo.getClassName();    
String packageName = componentInfo.getPackageName();
if(className.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.settings.Settings"))
{
    // DO YOUR JOB HERE
}
```